# while($row) not showing every row

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get my WHILE code to work. I want this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM udvalgte_kampe";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Then I want it to show all rows in the table, so I use:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['hold1'].' - '.$row['hold2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['hold3'].' - '.$row['hold4'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['hold5'].' - '.$row['hold6'].'</td>
          </tr>'
}
```

But it won't work? If I use just:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['hold1'].' - '.$row['hold2'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['hold3'].' - '.$row['hold4'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['hold5'].' - '.$row['hold6'].'</td>
      </tr>'
```

It works fine, but only shows the one row. Please help!

Comment: What does "won't work" mean with your while loop?

Comment: This is not all of the code, is it? My guess is that you're fetching the query results more than once, so you never get the first row when you try to loop.

Comment: *But it won't work?* do you ask us? or you describe the result you've got?

Comment: Seems that you have only one row in the database. What says `echo $query->num_rows;`?

Comment: FWIW, `mysqli_query` is returning a _result_, not a query.  Your code would be more readible if you named your result variable `$result` rather than `$query` which makes it look lke you're passing the SQL to the `mysqli_fetch_array()` call.

Comment: When I write the first code with the `while`-part, the site just comes with an error. So that's what I mean with 'won't work'. 
@JustOnUnderMillions I have 3 rows :)

Comment: What is the error the site returns?

Comment: Finally I guess you just missed semicolon after `</tr>'` so just set it to `</tr>';` when echo ;-)

Comment: just change mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_assoc and make sure you only have 1 fetch for 1 query then it will work

Comment: @Alex Are you kidding me!?!? That was the issue! Oh dear God, I have tried for hours, and I just missed the semicolon. Haha, well, thank you. Can't accept your answer when it's a comment though :/

Comment: That is not an answer :-)  "thank you" is enough. good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try foreach works similar to while loop. Make sure you have multiple rows in database.

```
<?Php    
    $sql = "select * from trainer";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    foreach($query as $row){ 
    echo '<tr>
              <td>'.$row['hold1'].' - '.$row['hold2'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['hold3'].' - '.$row['hold4'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['hold5'].' - '.$row['hold6'].'</td>
          </tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: That actually did it :) I'm really not sure what was wrong before. But thank you! :)

Comment: That was a semicolon `;`  ;-)

Comment: I use mysqli_fetch_assoc() not fetch_array, array is finicky for us sometimes

Comment: If you have your table setup right and query written properly mysql_fetch_assoc() is the way to go, code readability wise $result['username'] is easier to understand than $result[0].

Comment: S that semicolon u missed and I missed to inform..;-)

Comment: OP hast to fetch the rows from the database. The result of `mysqli_query()` is not an array.